# mail command successful, but mail was not received by recipient

Tags: email, smtp, mail-transport-agent

I used `mail`, its exit status is zero but the recepient is not receiving any mail. What could be the problem?

I used this code:

```
mylinsystem:/etc/mail # mail -v -s "test" test_user@receipient_domain.com </tmp/txt
test_user@receipient_domain.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 mylinsystem.receipient_domain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.6/8.13.6/SuSE Linux 0.8; Thu, 27 Nov 2014 00:25:47 +0530
>>> EHLO mylinsystem.receipient_domain.com
250-mylinsystem.receipient_domain.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> MAIL From:<root@mylinsystem.receipient_domain.com> SIZE=228
250 2.1.0 <root@mylinsystem.receipient_domain.com>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<test_user@receipient_domain.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <test_user@receipient_domain.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
250 2.0.0 sAQItljm015768 Message accepted for delivery
test_user@receipient_domain.com... Sent (sAQItljm015768 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 mylinsystem.receipient_domain.com closing connection
mylinsystem
```

If run `mailq` then I see the following message:

```
sAPLEEcO028725    14849 Wed Nov 26 02:44 <usr@mylinsystem.domain.com>
                 (Deferred: Connection timed out with [163.181.51.401])
                                         <test_user@receipient_domain.com>
```

Comment: `Connection timed out with [163.181.51.401])` Is that a copy-paste error, or something more sinister?

Answer (score 2):

`mail`'s exit status refers to local processing only. It means: "This mail has been accepted bei the local MTA." It cannot say anything about the success of delivering the mail as that has not even been tried at this point.

Comment: Thanks. Why delivering is not yet attempted. Can you please point out something so that i can invetigate in that direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's how mail works. mail is sent to one server, then another, and another, till it reaches the end. If you want to check that it's 'leaving' you end check /var/log/mail.log (or similar) http://en.kioskea.net/contents/116-how-email-works-mta-mda-mua has good info.